# Map and pattern matching

Tags: f#

I have an assignment here that I'm struggling with:

```
type multimap<'a,'b when 'a:comparison and 'b:comparison> = MMap of Map<'a, list<'b>>
```

The assignment states that

> We define the canonical representation of a multimap to be the representation where the elements in the
>   value-lists are ordered.
>     Declare a function `canonical: multimap<'a,'b> -> multimap<'a,'b> when 'a : comparison and 'b : comparison`
>   where `canonical m` returns the canonical representation of `m`.

Right now I have:

```
let toOrderedList (mm:multimap<'a,'b>)  = 
    match mm with
    | MMap m ->
```

I don't know how to pattern match on this. Any help? :3

Comment: **Hint:** [Map.map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ee353908.aspx) and of course [List.sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ee370323.aspx) ... now do the obvious

Comment: aside from this you can shorten your function a bit if you do the deconstruction right in with the parameter: `let toOrderedList (MMap m) = ...`

Comment: ... btw: the hints don't help you with the *pattern-match* - because you already did it (your `m` is a `Map<'a, 'b list>`) - what's left is do bring all the lists behind the keys into *order* (... sort them) - now of course you cannot mutate those `Maps<...>` - so you have to `map` the complete structure ... well now look at the hints ...

Comment: I was in great doubt when I look the the assignment, as I could not figure out how to work this out properly myself.

Comment: the question is: are you still in *doubt* ... look you have these puzzle tiles: `m`, `Map.map`, `List.sort` and `MMap`- now all you have to do is to put them together in the right way (with `|>` and `(fun ... -> ...)` for example) - the **types** will even help you if you look at it - those tiles really only fit one way

Comment: To me it seems difficult, as I have little experience in these kind of assignments. How to return the new multimap? This ain't working: let canonical (mm:multimap<'a,'b>) : multimap<'a,'b> = 
    match mm with
    | MMap m -> let newMap = Map.map (fun key value -> List.sort value)
                MMap newMap

Comment: you are on the right track! The first think that comes to mind is that you most likely forgot the `in` in `let ... in ...` somehere. And the second parameter to `Map.map` is something of type `Map<'key,'vale>` put you gave it the value-constructor `MMap` - but of course you will need the `MMap` somewhere too (because you want an `multimap` back - btw: you should write `Multimap` IMO but that is not important) ...

Comment: let me give you the first piece to work with: `let cannonical (MMap m) = Map.map (fun _ value -> List.sort value) ...` (you don't really need the `let ... in `) - but you probably will have to use `|>` here

Comment: I got it working. Thanks! ^_^

Comment: good job - you should probably write your own answer to the question and accept it later ;)

Comment: I will... I have got a whole bunch of assignments with this kind of types, so I will work my way through them to practise ^_^

Comment: As a side question ; what are (if any) the benefits of using a single case DU instead of a type alias `type Multimap<'a, 'b when 'a: comparison> = Map<'a, 'b list>` ?

Comment: the type-alias is just an alias - with this you could make `MMap` private and publish a smart-constructor (for example just as `let create = MMap >> cannonical` and you could only construct *cannonical* representations of `multimap`s

Comment: then you could later decide that `Map` has to bad performance - so you could easily switch to `Dictionary` internally without changing the outward interface - if could say that this is the FP way of encapsulation

Answer (score 2):

ok, just to give this an answer the function you are looking for can be written like this:

```
let cannonical (MMap m) = 
    m 
    |> Map.map (fun _ vs -> List.sort vs) 
    |> MMap
```

this deconstructs the `multimap` right in the argument definition (pattern-matching) and then pipes the `Map<>` `m` through - sorting the `list`s with `Map.map` and finally wrapping it back into `mulitmap` using the constructor `MMap`